# Getting error message from NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, warning-messages

I'm trying to solve for coefficients $k1$, $k2$, $k3$, $k4$ in the following equation:

$\det\left(\,\begin{bmatrix}k1+k2 & -k2 & 0\\-k2 & k2+k3 & -k3 \\ 0 & -k3 & k3+k4\end{bmatrix} -
\begin{bmatrix}\omega^2 & 0 & 0\\0 & \omega^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \omega^2\end{bmatrix}\,\right)=0$

where $\omega>0$ is such that $\frac{\omega_1}{2\pi}=0.0028$, $\frac{\omega_2}{2\pi}=0.0036$, $\frac{\omega_3}{2\pi}=0.0042$.

I've tried to solve this by substituting $\omega^2$ with `Replace`, yielding

> ```
> w == 
>   Root[-a b c - a b d - a c d - b c d + 
>    (3909 a b + 7818 a c + 11727 b c + 3909 a d + 7818 b d + 
>     3909 c d) #1 + (-15280281 a - 30560562 b - 30560562 c - 
>     15280281 d) #1^2 + 59730618429 #1^3 &, 1] || 
> w == 
>   Root[-a b c - a b d - a c d - b c d + 
>     (3909 a b + 7818 a c + 11727 b c + 3909 a d + 7818 b d + 
>     3909 c d) #1 + (-15280281 a - 30560562 b - 30560562 c - 
>     15280281 d) #1^2 + 59730618429 #1^3 &, 2] || 
> w == 
>   Root[-a b c - a b d - a c d - b c d + 
>    (3909 a b + 7818 a c + 11727 b c + 3909 a d + 7818 b d + 
>     3909 c d) #1 + (-15280281 a - 30560562 b - 30560562 c - 
>     15280281 d) #1^2 + 59730618429 #1^3 &, 3]
> ```

upon which I use `NSolve`:

```
equations = 
 {Root[
    -a b c - a b d - a c d - b c d + 
      (3909 a b + 7818 a c + 11727 b c + 3909 a d + 7818 b d + 3909 c d) #1 + 
      (-15280281 a - 30560562 b - 30560562 c - 15280281 d) #1^2 + 
      59730618429 #1^3 &, 
    1] == (0.0028*2*Pi)^2,
  Root[
    -a b c - a b d - a c d - b c d + 
      (3909 a b + 7818 a c + 11727 b c + 3909 a d + 7818 b d + 3909 c d) #1 + 
      (-15280281 a - 30560562 b - 30560562 c - 15280281 d) #1^2 + 
      59730618429 #1^3 &, 
    2] == (0.0036*2*Pi)^2,
  Root[
    -a b c - a b d - a c d - b c d + 
      (3909 a b + 7818 a c + 11727 b c + 3909 a d + 7818 b d + 3909 c d) #1 + 
      (-15280281 a - 30560562 b - 30560562 c - 15280281 d) #1^2 + 
     59730618429 #1^3 &, 
    3] == (0.0042*2*Pi)^2,
  a > 0,
  b > 0,
  c > 0,
  d > 0};

coeffs = NSolve[equations, {a, b, c, d}, Reals]
```

But I obtain the error message "Infinite solution set has dimension at least 1" and obtain `{}` as the output.

Does this mean that there are no solutions to the problem, or that I am solving this problem incorrectly? Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: You're solving essentially 2 equations for 4 unknowns. Use `Reduce`, but know that the solution space is likely (though not necessarily) a 2 dimensional object. The equation does have solutions, it has an infinite number of them. See `FindInstance` if you only need one possible solution chosen more or less at random.

Comment: I've tried using `FindInstance`, but the calculation seems to take a long time (I haven't actually tried letting it run all the way, I stopped it after around 5 minutes).

Answer (score 2):

For the first $\omega$, the following use of `FindInstance` finds a `{k1, k2, k3, k4}` tuple that satisfies the equation more or less instantly.

```
FindInstance[
 Det[{{k1 + k2, -k2, 0}, {-k2, k2 + k3, -k3}, {0, -k3, 
       k3 + k4}} - {{w^2, 0, 0}, {0, w^2, 0}, {0, 0, w^2}}] == 0 /. 
  w -> (2 π 0.0028),
 {k1, k2, k3, k4}]
```

The solution space for this value of $\omega$ can be found with `Reduce`, but it doesn't easily simplify to anything obviously and inherently meaningful:

```
Reduce[Det[{{k1 + k2, -k2, 0}, {-k2, k2 + k3, -k3}, {0, -k3, 
       k3 + k4}} - {{w^2, 0, 0}, {0, w^2, 0}, {0, 0, w^2}}] == 0 /. 
  w -> (2 π 0.0028)]
```

Comment: This only results in finding one such `{k1, k2, k3, k4}` tuple which such that one root results in $\omega_1$ though. Simplifying the equation results in:

`k1 k2 k3 + k1 k2 k4 + k1 k3 k4 + k2 k3 k4 + (-3909 k1 k2 - 7818 k1 k3 - 11727 k2 k3 - 3909 k1 k4 - 7818 k2 k4 - 3909 k3 k4) w + (15280281 k1 + 30560562 k2 + 30560562 k3 + 15280281 k4) w^2 - 59730618429 w^3 == 0`, which is a polynomial, and I want to find values for the coefficients `{k1, k2, k3, k4}` which results in those roots

Comment: `FindInstance` cannot find an infinite solution set, but you can have it find as many solutions as you wish by say, `FindInstance[..., {k1, k2, k3, k4}, 10]`, to find 10 solutions. You could also do `FindInstance[..., {k1, k2, k3, k4}, Reals, 10]` to find 10 strictly real solutions.